# Is it feasible to be using a hash table to store questions and answers?

Tags: java

I am currently developing a cue card application and I am finally at the part where I should be coding the source code the deals with storing "answers" to each individual cue card. Each individual card has a question(key) and an answer(value). After looking through the internet I found that I can use a Hash Table or a two dimensional array.

I'm mostly worried about "size" because if I have 20 cards for my Biology cue card set and each has at least 2 to 4 sentences for the answer then it can get quite big. This brings up the question of reallocating space as we add more cards. Would a Hash table be feasible in terms of access and storing or should I stay simple and just use a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: You do not need to be concerned about the memory requirements of a flash card system with less than a thousand cards.

Comment: So is hash table a good way of implementing my flash card application?

Comment: What is wrong with `ArrayList<FlashCard>` (and `FlashCard` contains all information about this card --- question, answers, score value, tags, category etc)?

Comment: "as we add more cards". First thing you should do (after you got this going) is to externalize the card definitions into text files you can easily edit.

Comment: Making a `FlashCard` object would probably be a better design like Thilo said, but a hash map will still get the job done.

Comment: Use the datastructure that makes sense: do you have a sequence or a map? Sometimes (but more rarely) it is both.